# libreoffice find all in column A like "doctor*" OR LIKE "Fysio*" then column B = 2.3

Tags: function, libreoffice

[image]I try to fill column B with data depending of the text in column A.
Find all in column A like "doctor*" OR LIKE "Fysio*" OR LIKE "Admin*" then column B = 2.3. **Means search text including with wildcard *** .

I only get a result when do this simple query:

> =IF(A2="doctor*";2.3;0)

Someone an idea how to fix this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the [functions that support regular expressions](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc#Regular_expressions_in_Calc_functions).

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("doctor|Fysio|Admin";A2));0;2.3)
```

[SEARCH](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SEARCH) supports regular expressions, and [ISERROR](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#ISERROR) handles the error if the pattern does not match.

[image: 2.3 for matches in column B]

Comment: Thanks but in libreoffice it does not work. I get  0 as result. libreoffice is not 100% equal to openoffice.

Comment: @jtermaat: In this case, there is no difference.  The screenshot is from LibreOffice 5.4.3.2 on Windows.  Please tell what version and locale you are using.  Did you specify settings correctly according to the instructions in the link?  A screen capture would help to show the failed result.

Comment: See screenshots above from options and from the sheet

Comment: Did you start with an entirely new document and try my example?  The text in your example is upper case - "Doctor" instead of "doctor" - but that seems to work anyway.  Can you upload the document somewhere and provide a link?  For non-English locales, [use English function names](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Formula_1#Use_English_function_names).

Comment: OK, I see a problem.  There is a discrepancy between `2.3` and `2,3` in the question.  What is the decimal format for your locale?  Please tell what locale you are using as shown under *Help -> LibreOffice*.

Comment: Default delimiter for decimals = "." US style. Language settings is English + keyboard = US.